# Get @vue/test-utils@1.3.0 working with @vue/compat@3.1.0

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vuejs3

Has anyone gotten @vue/test-utils@1.3.0 to work with @vue/compat@3.1.0? It looks like test-utils is looking at the vue@3 module instead of the vue-compat module.

```
// when I run my tests
    ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Cannot set property 'productionTip' of undefined

    > 1 | import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
        | ^
```

from vue-test-utils.js. `Vue_default` is probably vue3 since `config` is deprecated?

```
Vue__default['default'].config.productionTip = false; //
```

Running the app in dev seems to work fine since webpack is mapping 'vue' to compat. Maybe there is something similar for `jest.config`?

```
// this is what's working for webpack.
declare module 'vue' {
    import { CompatVue } from '@vue/runtime-dom'
    const Vue: CompatVue
    export default Vue
    export * from '@vue/runtime-dom'
    const { configureCompat } = Vue
    export { configureCompat }
}
```

Mapping vue to @vue/compat in the jest.config moduleNameMapper yields a different issue

```
'moduleNameMapper': {
    '^vue$': '@vue/compat',
  },

// error when running tests
TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property '$emit'
```